# Null pointer exception when loading fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-listfragment

I am working on my final project in android-programming course (so I'm still pretty new). I'm building my own media player. I implemented a Drawer that contains the different media types (video, audio, stream etc.) and what I want is to have each clicked item load a fragment that will tackle the task. The first one I'm working on is the audio fragment. It is th esecond on the list but i think it'll e easier than the video. Anyway. when I click on "audio" ([picture link](http://postimg.org/image/9a9zdkshf/af6b1aca/)) I get a null pointer exception. I've been trying to figure it out for a couple of days but now I'm really wasting precious time. What am I doing wrong?

Because there is quite a lot of code involved I'll use snippets (if people prefer I actually paste all the code here, let me know and I'll change it).

MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/zsXuZHkN

FragmentAudio: http://pastebin.com/77XsBbu9

ListAdapterAudio: http://pastebin.com/cfu7azP0

logact log:

```
09-13 18:31:33.056  11959-11959/com.example.ref_apps.winnerplayer E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ref_apps.winnerplayer, PID: 11959
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:414)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:449)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:441)
        at com.example.ref_apps.winnerplayer.MainActivity.selectDrawerItem(MainActivity.java:118)
        at com.example.ref_apps.winnerplayer.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:64)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1153)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3065)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4031)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

there are other files, obviously, but I don't think that they are the culprits. I'll add file by request.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is there an exception thrown at line 111 in `MainActivity`? You create your fragment in kinda strange way, wouldn't it be easier to use a Fragment constructor in that switch? I think this `fragmentClass.newInstance()` fails and therefore `fragment` is null and NPE is thrown when you try to load it.

Comment: Honestly, I stole this idea from a tutorial. It really seemed to make sense but maybe it's my inexperience. Could you elaborate a little on your suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Activity you are importing `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and your Fragment is `android.app.Fragment`.  That's why your cast fails after calling `newInstance()` and your fragment is null.  The same goes with your `ListFragment`.

You also need to implement `newInstance()` in your fragment.

```
public static Fragment newInstance() 
{
    FragmentAudio myFragment = new FragmentAudio();
    return myFragment;
}
```

Comment: Similarly you should import `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment` instead of `android.app.ListFragment`

Comment: kphil - I tried changing the import but now, in beinTransaction() I get an error stating that it expects v4.    @headuck in what file? I cannot find any such import..

Comment: In FragmentVideo (and other fragment class as well). You should use Fragment from support library in the entire application.

Comment: If you are using `android.app.Fragment` and `android.app.ListFragment` now, you need to call `beginTransaction()` from `getFragmentManager()` not `getSupportFragmentManager()`. `getSupportFragmentManager()` works for `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and `android.support.v4.app.ListFragment`.

Comment: I finally got it to work.. I removed any trace of supported library except for the drawer (which i didn't upload here) and kept getting null pointers. I then looked at every single instance I call of any type of class and founf that I hadn't initialized the `ArrayList`. I had several more problems after but finally got it to work. 
I appreciate all the effort by the two of you!

Answer (score 1):

Try after adding addToBackstack(null) in fragment replace.

(or)

Check backStack count and you should clear all the count before replace another fragment.

Comment: won't this cause the previous fragment to lose all its data? I mean - imagine you are using a media player and moving from video to audio - I would prefer it saved the state of the video and be able to return to it. Wont you suggestion mean that this is no longer possible?

Comment: I don't know why you're not bothering to answer my question. All i can say is that I added your code but found that it has absolutely no effect.