# NullPointerException in Fragment Manager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

Can anyone please help me solve this exception?
This is the code of fragment manager and how to show my fragment in activity

```
private void selectItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = null;
    // minus 1 because we have header that has 0 position
    if (position < 1) { // because we have header, we skip clicking on it
        return;
    }
    switch (position) {
        case 2:
            fragment = new TextViewsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            //fragment = new ProfilFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            //fragment = new AttendanceFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            //fragment = new PermitFragment();
            break;
        case 6:
            //Logout();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    commitFragment(fragment);

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mDrawerItems.get(position - 1).getTitle());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
private class CommitFragmentRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public CommitFragmentRunnable(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
}

public void commitFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    // Using Handler class to avoid lagging while
    // committing fragment in same time as closing
    // navigation drawer
    mHandler.post(new CommitFragmentRunnable(fragment));
}
```

the exception point to `.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();`

Exception getting :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:416)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:451)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.replace(BackStackRecord.java:443)
            at com.csform.android.uiapptemplate.LeftMenusActivity$CommitFragmentRunnable.run(LeftMenusActivity.java:221)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

i tried to call one fragment into my activity by choose the left menu, but it get exception null pointer.

Comment: Because you are getting getSupportFragmentManager(); in different thread not ui thread.!!

Comment: then how to solve this?
i want to show my fragment at this activity

Comment: then how to get the fragment then?
i use this code in my another app, but it works normally...

Comment: You have to call this method in activity not in fragment..!!

Comment: it's in activity, not fragment -_- see my update

Comment: Refer this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551319/null-pointer-exception-when-loading-fragment/32551448#32551448) . It may help you

Comment: @ lindha dwi ambarwati : Call it in constructor and save reference of it..!!

Comment: are your sure your fragment is not null? because your switch case default did not create any fragment

Comment: yeah, when i choose the position 2, i got this exception.

Comment: check if your fragment container is R.id.content_frame and shown in activity

Comment: please check the Mamata Gelanee's comment, 
Because you are getting getSupportFragmentManager(); in different thread not ui thread.!! –  Mamata Gelanee

Comment: yeah i'm sure, i use 'FrameLayout' for my container

Comment: @LinhNguyen it's ui thread sir...
cek my update code. that class is inside activity

Answer (score 1):

refer to Mamata Gelanee's comment :

```
private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ......
      fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    }
```

Then in your runnable :

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
    }
```

Comment: then it's get exception again

Comment: android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@21c4a268 that was originally bound here
            at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:979)
            at

Comment: @lindhadwiambarwati thats different app. its not about your app -.-

Comment: i got this exception in my app, when i trying to show my fragment, it not responding and get this exception -_-

Comment: still get null exception

Comment: @lindhadwiambarwati student of UGM university? can you show me the full code of your activity and fragment?

Comment: @lindhadwiambarwati nope. nothing wrong with your activity

Comment: @lindhadwiambarwati then the culprit is not in your activity, i cannot check your whole project. debug it and find which one is null